# Is there any API that takes users’ emails and returns details of information of their Facebook username

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I found few third party API's  are providing information about facebook user based on their emaild , And i wonder the graph api not providing this functionality and how these API able to do ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to get the username by email. In fact, there is no API to get any Facebook user details by email. Also, there is no API to get the username, the only way to get any user info is by letting that specific user authorize your App.

You can only search for users by name: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#search

Comment: Full contact API and Pipl API takes email as inputs and get info facebook

Comment: they may have some special deal with facebook, who knows. but there is nothing you can do on your own. just check out the docs, and several questions about the same issue on stackoverflow.